# Calling one script after another

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, submit, addeventlistener

I am trying to use two java scripts on the same page my code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>       
    <script src="socket.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
  <div id="questionbox" width="100%"><%=data%></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');    

  socket.emit('questionreq',{res:'send me question'});
  questionbox = document.getElementById('questionbox');

  socket.on('question',function(res){
    question = res.question;
    optA = res.A;
    optB = res.B;
    optC = res.C;
    optD = res.D;
    answer = res.ans;

    questionbox.innerHTML += '<br>' + question + '<br>A:<input type="radio" name="question" id="A" value="A">' + optA + '<br>B <input type="radio" id="B" name="question" value="B">' + optB + '<br>'+ 'C :<input type="radio" name="question" id="C" value="C">' + optC + '<br>'+'D :<input type="radio" name="question" id="D" value="D">' + optD + '<br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">'
  });    
</script>
<script>                                          
   btnSubmit=document.getElementById("submit");                                          
   btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {                                          
     if (document.getElementById("A").checked)
       useranswer="A";
     else if (document.getElementById("B").checked)
       useranswer="B";
     else if (document.getElementById("C").checked)
       useranswer="C";
     else
       useranswer="D";
     if (1) {
       alert('correct!!!');
       socket.emit('correct',{res:'I am correct'});
     }
   });
</script>
```

Here I am working with node.js so first script is to request for a question to the server and render it to the html page. And second script gives an alert when user clicks on the on the submit button, but this second script is not getting called can you please tell what is wrong with this script.

Comment: You really dont need two scripts to do that. you can put second script also in first script it self

Comment: script tag inside another script is not working. @Dinesh

Comment: dont put enite script tag inside another script tag.copy your only js code

Comment: Do not put script tags after the html end tag. You need to put them inside the body or head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really dont need two seperate script tags. keep second script inside socket.emit of first script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>


     <script src="socket.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="questionbox" width="100%"><%=data%></div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
        var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

          socket.emit('questionreq',{res:'send me question'});
          questionbox=document.getElementById('questionbox');

        socket.on('question',function(res){
         question=res.question;
         optA=res.A;
         optB=res.B;
         optC=res.C;
         optD=res.D;
         answer=res.ans;
         
         questionbox.innerHTML+='<br>'+question+'<br>A:<input type="radio" name="question" id="A" value="A">'+optA+'<br>B <input type="radio" id="B" name="question" value="B">'+optB+'<br>'+'C :<input type="radio" name="question" id="C" value="C">'+optC+'<br>'+'D :<input type="radio" name="question" id="D" value="D">'+optD+'<br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">';
var btnSubmit=document.getElementById("submit"); 

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click',function(){
                                      if(document.getElementById("A").checked)
                                        useranswer="A";
                                        else if(document.getElementById("B").checked)
                                        useranswer="B";
                                        else if(document.getElementById("C").checked)
                                        useranswer="C";
                                        else
                                         useranswer="D";
                                       if(1){
                                           alert('correct!!!');
                                          socket.emit('correct',{res:'I am correct'});
                                       }
                                       
                                      });
           });
                                     
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to help. I recommend you to  Learn about callbacks. how to handle asynchronous.